# Executing an onclick from the URL?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a website that I visit frequently which has various product pages like such:

product.html?orderid=1000

product.html?orderid=1001

product.html?orderid=1002

etc..

Within each of these pages there is a confirmation button I need to press..

```
<a type="button" id="confirm" onclick="confirm(this)" class="lpb" data-orderID="1000"><i class="loading-box" style="display:none"><span class="animate-rotate">&#xe67c;</span></i>Confirm</a>
```

I am trying to manipulate the URL to incorporate this submission, so rather than be visiting product.html?orderid=1001
I'd be visiting something like product.html?orderid=1001?id=confirm
but obviously I've no clue how to arrive at that.. any support would be great

thanks

Comment: The url leads somewhere, just link to that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  You can put any values you want in the query string (though they'd be separated by a `&` character, not additional `?` characters), but what's your goal here?

Comment: You want to append `&id=confirm` when you click on Confirm button and re-load the same page?

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response both
yes I basically want to load the product page once
currently I'm loading it twice, once to open the page, once to press the confirm button.. I know that every time I visit the product pages (regardless of product ID) that there is a confirm button, so I want to skip the initial load and go straight to the confirm, so i'm halving my steps.. sorry if I'm not being clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the url leads to somewhere, just link to that (like @Martijn commented above). If it doesn't or `confirm()` does anything important, you could use a userscript with [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=de). Edit the `@match <your website url here>` with the website you're using the script for.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        <your website url here>
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    let el = document.getElementById('confirm');
    if (el) el.click();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to construct a URL that will load a page and then execute JavaScript on it.

You would have to edit the page to examine the `location` object when the page loads and act according to what its value is.

Answer (score 0):

Here i set value to ID.:

```
 <a type="button" id="1000" onclick="confirm(this)" class="lpb" data-orderID="1000"><i class="loading-box" style="display:none"><span class="animate-rotate">&#xe67c;</span></i>Confirm</a>
```

Give Id to dynamic and when you click on link then it will go with browser URL: and you also set the basepath of the site.

```
function confirm(thisEvent,eventName){
        var basePath="http://basepath.url.com/";
        window.location.href =basePath"product.html?orderid="+eventName.target.id;
    }
```